# React TipTap - Unexptected cursor behaviour on custom TaskItem

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

I've just started using https://tiptap.dev as a framework for rich text editing.

I'm using a custom React component based on the TaskItem extension.
When I use these assigned keyboard shortcuts I get the expected result but the cursor isn't following into newly created nodes (see video below).

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14828061/193038744-bd04b1a3-27f2-49e4-bcbb-f93a8243bd22.mov

I've recreated the issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-roentgen-9qhb23?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a strange behavior. With a pure JS created `node-view`, the cursor jumps to new line as one would expect. With React rendered `node-view`, there are some wrappings of `div` around what's actually rendered in DOM. I suspect those might be interfering with the working of `splitListItem` as desired (but not totally sure).

I can get the jumping to next list item behavior as follows though :-

```js
      Enter: () => {
        this.editor.commands.splitListItem("taskItem")
        const endPos = this.editor.state.tr.selection.anchor;        
        this.editor.chain().focus(endPos);
        return true;
      },
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a perfect workaround. I appreciate your help!